# Displaying Cmake variables without running Cmake on CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have a package called Foo. If I run cmake on a CMakeLists.txt file that contains `find_package(Foo)`, then I can print out the values of variables such as `${Foo_LIBRARIES}` and `${Foo_INCLUDES}`.

Is there an easy way to display these variables without having to run cmake on a CMakeLists.txt file, and without having to manually inspect the config.cmake file?